# Adding Map markers to Google Maps with array methods using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I'm trying to add map Markers and info windows to my map using a `forEach()` method and a `map()` method for the info windows to attach to the markers.

Here is my code so far:

```
//String to display in info window
var content;

//Declare Map variable and markers array
var map;
var marker;
var markers = [];



// cache Info window in a variable
var window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

//Create Instance of a map from the Google maps api
//Grab the reference to the "map" id to display map
//Set the map options object properties 
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: {lat: 40.440624, lng: -79.995888},
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
};

// tells the view model what to do when a change occurs
function gymLocation(value) {
    this.name = ko.observable(value.name);
    this.address = ko.observable(value.address);
    this.description = ko.observable(value.description);
    this.lat = ko.observable(value.lat);
    this.lng = ko.observable(value.lng);
};


//ViewModel
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    //Copies the values of initialLocations and stores them in sortedLocations(); observableArray
    self.sortedLocations = ko.observableArray(initialLocations.slice());

    //Adds new markers at each location in the initialLocations Array
    self.sortedLocations().forEach(function(location) {
        marker = new google.map.Marker({
            position: location.latlng,
            map: map,
            title: location.name
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    });

    //Map info windows to each item in the markers array
    self.markers.map(function(info) {
        info.addListener('click', function() {
            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                position: info.latlng,
                map: map,
                title: info.name
            });
        });
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel());
```

When I load the the page in my browser, the only thing I can get to display is the map itself. I checked the console for errors and I am receiving,

> app.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Marker' of undefined

Am I missing something? or could this be an issue with the scope within the function?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the exact error message right? (I.e. isn't it 'marker' instead of "Marker"?). Also, it would be easier for us to help / repro your issue if you trimmed your code a bit, see [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: Marker is the google.maps.Marker constructor. Where as the marker is the variable i'm trying to store it in.

Comment: Is google js script file loaded at that point?

Comment: Makes sense, that `Marker` is a constructor function. However, the exact phrase "Marker" does *not* occur anywhere in your snippet. (My pattern-matching-fu may be off base here, but it felt strange nonetheless.)

Comment: I got it working. It was a stupid mistake. Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you are referencing the `google.map` object in the `var marker = new google.map.Marker` call, which as it seems is undefined meaning that the compiler cannot find the referenced object. I believe what you intended to reference was the `google.maps` (plural) object, which you correctly referenced when creating the map `map = new google.maps.Map`.

See attached link for an image of your code after making the fix.
[Link to image of your Google Map's App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMnyf.jpg)